# Insert Javascript Inside Text Value

Tags: javascript, html

How can i insert this javascript inside my "price" text value? Here's my code:

```js
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('car-select')[document.getElementById('car-select').selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="input-group pick-up">

<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>Price </span>

<input name="price" type="text" class="form-control autocomplete-location" id="price" value="">

</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: what do mean insert the js into the value?

Comment: did you try just setting document.getElementById("price").value=x;

Comment: Where is the element with `'car-select'` id?

Answer (score 0):

As said by MiiinimalLogic, just try to add

```
document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value =  x;
```

If you want `x` to appear in your price input.

---

If you want to call this function whenever price field is changed, use instead

```
document.getElementsByName("price")[0].onchange=function(){

    var x = document.getElementById('car-select')[document.getElementById('car-select').selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;
};
```